# Is $f(x) = Cx\log x$ the only solution to $f(xy) = xf(y) + yf(x)$?

Tags: functional-equations

I was studying $L(x) = x \log x$ function and found that it satisfies the following functional equation for positive $x, y$:
$$
f: \mathbb R^+ \to \mathbb R\\
f(xy) = x f(y) + y f(x)
$$
I have a feeling that $L(x)$ is the only (up to multiplying by a constant term) solution to that equation. How do I show that?

Comment: Let $f(x)=x\log{x}$. Do I miss anything: $\sout{f(xy)=xy\log{xy}=xy\log{x}+xy\log{y}\neq x\log{y}+y\log{x}=xf(y)+yf(x)}$. Apologies..

Comment: @rafforaffo Nope. $xy\log x + xy\log y = y(x\log x) + x(y \log y) = yf(x) + xf(y)$.

Comment: And my previous comment is clearly false...apologies

Comment: An operation that satisfies this (or rather $f(xy) = xf(y) + f(x)y$) is called a derivation. If $x$ and $y$ were themselves functions, then differentiation is one such operation. Not that it helps you much.

Comment: @Arthur yes, noticed that too

Comment: You can find much more information about this matter in the following paper: H. Goldmann, P. ˇSemrl; Multiplicative derivations on C(X) ,Monatsh. Math. 121(1996), 189–197.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Introduce a new function $g : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ by

$$g(x) = e^{-x} f(e^x).$$

Then satisfies the [*Cauchy's functional equation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_functional_equation)

$$g(x+y) = g(x) + g(y).$$

This equation is extensively studied, and even a mild regularity condition will force the solution to be of the form $g(x) = cx$. On the other hand, under the Axiom of Choice we can construct a solution which is *not* of this form.

Comment: I suppose, we wish to find continous solution

Answer (score 6):

I suppose the function $f$ is differentiable.
Let $y=1$, it is easy to check $f(1)=0$.

Then, 
$$\lim_{y\rightarrow 1}\frac{f(xy)-f(x)}{xy-x}=\lim_{y\rightarrow 1}\frac{xf(y)+yf(x)-f(x)}{xy-x}=\frac{f(x)}{x}+\lim_{y\rightarrow 1}\frac{f(y)-f(1)}{y-1}$$
We obtain a differential equation,
$$f'(x)=\frac{f(x)}{x}+f'(1)$$
And it is easy to find the solution is 
$$f(x)=f'(1)xlnx$$

Comment: I had a similar solution by setting $x=x$ and $y=1+\frac{h}{x}$ and then defining derivative and taking limit.

Answer (score 5):

Since the domain of $f$ is $\Bbb R_+$, we get an equivalent condition by dividing both sides by $xy$, namely
$$\frac{f(xy)}{xy} = \frac{f(x)}{x} + \frac{f(y)}{y}.$$
By definition, this holds iff the function
$$g(x) := \frac{f(x)}{x}$$
satisfies
$$g(xy) = g(x) + g(y);$$
a function that satisfies this latter property is called *additive*.

Now, any monotonic additive function on $\Bbb R_+$ is a multiple of $\log x$ (this can be found at Dieudonné, Jean (1969). *Foundations of Modern Analysis 1*. Academic Press. p. 84.). So, if we require this condition on $g$, we have $$g(x) = C \log x$$
and hence
$$f(x) = C x \log x$$
as desired.

On the other hand, not all additive functions are monotonic, so there are functions $f$ that satisfy the function equation but which are not of the indicated form.

Comment: Both papers you've provided are about arithmetic functions, i.e. defined on $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: @uranix Oops, you're right, I've replaced the reference.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to William Huang solution, here's what i tried.

First note that $f(1)=0$ and $f(0)=0.$

Now let us set $x=x$ and $y=1+\frac{h}{x}$

Which will give us, $f(x+h)=xf\left(1+\frac{h}{x}\right)+\left(1+\frac{h}{x}\right)f(x)$

Which simplifies to, $$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\frac{x}{h}f\left(1+\frac{h}{x}\right)+\frac{f(x)}{x}$$.

Now, taking limits we will have.

$f'(x)=L+\frac{f(x)}{x}$

Where $$L=\lim_\limits{h\to 0}\frac{f\left(1+\frac{h}{x}\right)}{\frac{h}{x}}$$ , which is of form $\frac{0}{0}$. Hence we can apply lhopitals rule to see that $L=f'(1)$.

Hence $f'(x)=f'(1)+\frac{f(x)}{x}$

Yet the solution to which is, $f(x)=f'(1)x \ln x$